# Emit throttled file load progress in redux-saga through eventChannel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, throttling

I'm using [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) with [eventChannel](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/Channels.md#user-content-using-the-eventchannel-factory-to-connect-to-external-events) in order to handle resource loading with progress tracking.

I was wondering what's the best pattern in order to debounce load-progress event that are too frequent. Am I supposed to handle that at a lower level with a [throttled](https://github.com/niksy/throttle-debounce#readme) emission

```
import {
  eventChannel,
  END
} from 'redux-saga'
import request from 'superagent';
import { throttle } from 'throttle-debounce';



function loadFile(url) {
  return eventChannel(emitter => {

    const emitProgress = (emitter, payload) => emitter(payload);
    const emitProgressThrottled = throttle(500, emitProgress);

    request.post(url)
      .on('progress', event => {
        const payload = {
          percent: event.percent,
          type: 'progress'
        };

        emitProgressThrottled(emitter, payload)            

      })
      .then(res => {
        const payload = {
          data: res.body,
          type: 'finish'
        };

        emitter(payload);
        emitter(END);
      })
  })
}
```

or is it better to handle that within redux-saga *scope* [throttling](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#throttlems-pattern-saga-args) the inbound pattern emitted by `eventChannel`?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would throttle it at redux-saga scope. This enables every service using that channel to decide whether they want to throttle it or not and you will avoid using an extra library. That said, if you are confident that you will always want to throttle it, the lower level solution will probably safe you some writing. Neither solution is wrong.

Comment: @MartinKadlec you got a point. Actually I agree that it is strictly dependent on the granularity and design of the state-management. My opinion is that the rate of progress event emission might burden too much (especially with heavy file-size load) the redux/redux-saga. Hence the lower level throttling approach, given that progress notification through the web-UI progress-bar is relevant yet not critical (loose updates are to be considered acceptable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple pf weeks have passed since I originally posted the question and I made my thoughts clearer.

For the described scenario I preferred the lower level throttle approach (code in the above question body). Isolating the API operational scope as well as avoiding  additional load to the [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) middleware seems more reasonable to me.

As [@Martin Kadlec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2347716/martin-kadlec) correctly pointed out, both solution are to be considered acceptable. Which one you'll choose is bonded more with software design patterns and personal preferences.